# remove all the lines from file starting from "{" to "}" using sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, tr

I have a file whose contents are like this :

```
control_data {
some data dadadadf 
some data fsfsfs
some more data
.
.
.
}
more data below 
{
.
.
}
```

I want to delete the data from "control_data" to the first "}"

I tried a command

```
sed "s/control_data\([^}]*\)}//g"
```

but this only works if we do not have multiple lines eg. this command works when we have data like:

```
control_data {some data dadadadf some data fsfsfs some more data...}more data
```

It gives :

```
more data {....}
```

How to make this command work when we have data across multiple lines ?
I am new to shell scripting some explanation with answer will go a long way in helping.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use awk or you want something in sed alone?

Comment: @Raghuram i am in a process of learning sed it will be great if you can do it with sed otherwise awk will also do but please give an explanation also with the answer ..Thanks

Comment: Can this braced syntax nest?  Can this syntax contain `{` characters whose meaning is changed (e.g. inside string literals, or otherwise escaped? Could there be something like `foo { bar { "nested{stuff" } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one may not be an ideal one but this used sed(your sed code)

```
cat ip_file.txt | tr '\n' ':' | sed "s/control_data\([^}]*\)}//g" | tr ':' '\n'
```

Logic: I am converting all new lines to : and then using your sed code and then converting all : to newlines
Note : My assumption is : wont be present in the file anywhere.

Comment: that is beautiful :) .. i will try to remember this trick for long ...thanks

Comment: two things to be aware off with this. 1) will not work as expected with files that contain `:`. 2) may be inefficient for large files. Works in this case nonetheless. +1

Comment: You are assuming sed will accept a line with no EOL. Legacy sed implementations might just ignore such an incomplete line.

Comment: You can fix the lack of newline like this: `{ tr '\n' ':' < ip_file.txt; echo; } | sed ...`

Answer (score 2):

My sed-fu is weak, but here's what I got working (using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462013/delete-matching-nth-line-until-blank-line-in-awk-sed-grep/4463707#4463707) as a guide):

```
[me@home]$ sed -n '/^control_data {/{:a;n;/^}/!ba;n};p' input_file.txt
more data below 
{
.
.
}
```

Here's a breakdown of the command

```
sed -n "             # "-n" = suppress automatic printing of pattern space
/^control_data {/ {  # if (line matches control data)
   :a;                 #   mark this spot with label a
   n;                  #   get next line
   /^}/!ba             #   if (doesn't start with "}") go back to label a
   n;                  #   get next line before leaving this control block
};                   # end if
p;                   # print everything else not affected by previous block
" input_file.txt
```

Comment: if your sed-fu is weak then i do not know what to call my level of sed-fu .. the above solution works but it will take me sometime to fully understand it. Can you tell if everytime you are returning to label a and deleting line with "}" how everything is deleted

Comment: @user1271244 after going back to the label, we then get the next line without doing anything with the current line. Note that with the `-n` option, doing nothing means not printing it out (hence the `p;` at the end to print out lines not affected by the block

Comment: I've changed `d;` to `n;` to make it less confusing

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^control_data {.*}$/d;/^control_data {/,/^}$/d' file
```

- The first command removes all single lines `/^control_data {.*}$/d`
- The second command removes all blocks `/^control_data {/,/^}$/d`

Comment: This is by far the clearest answer.  Indeed simply `sed '/^control_data {/,/^}$/d'` works fine for the given test case.  The other answers are valid, but use techniques which are unnecessarily funky, and so obscure the simple problem with a simple solution.  I won't go as far as downvoting the other answers (because they're not wrong), but they make it look much harder than it is.